# android:String index out of bound

Tags: android, exception

I am making an app in which i am stuck in this exception - String index out of bound and i get error at the following line.

```
String netwrkk = mTelephonyMgr.getNetworkOperator();
 System.out.println("hello");
 if (netwrkk != null) {
     System.out.println("hello2");
      //  int mcc = Integer.parseInt(netwrkk.substring(0, 3)); // exception at this line

     System.out.println("hello3");
        int mnc = Integer.parseInt(netwrkk.substring(3));// exception at this line
        System.out.println("hello4");
     mccc1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mccc1);
     System.out.println("netwrk:"+netwrkk);
     mccc1.setText(Integer.toString(mcc));
     mncc1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mncc1);
     System.out.println("netwrk:"+netwrkk);
     mncc1.setText(Integer.toString(mnc));
     System.out.println("mccc: "+mcc);
     try{
     System.out.println("bearing : "+locn.getBearing());
     }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }System.out.println("mnc"+mnc);
                        }
```

Comment: What is the length of **netwrkk** string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if `netwrkk` has the length of 4 or more. If not, the `substring(0, 3)` will fail.

Also make yourself familiar with the `Log` class in android. You shouldn't use `System.out.println()`

Comment: what is main difference in log and System.out.println()? Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: The Log class is the class you should use to log. The output will be in the LogCat (like System.out.println) but you can filter the output and you can add a tag to it, to help identifying which class produced the output. Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html